# Trigger addClass on mouserover using 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create on hover color change of buttons using javascript code, the unclear part for me is how to set up 'this' attribute so the hovered element trigger the css part for specific button.

```js
$('this').mouseover(function() {
  $('#div').removeClass('svg-active');
  $('#span').removeClass('light-blue-link');
});
$('this').mouseout(function() {
  $('#div').removeClass('svg-active');
  $('#span').removeClass('light-blue-link');
});
```

```css
.button-outer {
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.button {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button::before {
  display:inline-block;
  content:'';
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.light-blue-link {
 color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}

span {
 font-weight: 300;
 transition: color 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='button-outer'>



  <div class='button'>
    <div id='div' class='svg profile'></div>
    <span id='span' class=''>Profile</span>
  </div>
  <div class='button'>
    <div id='div' class='svg friends'></div>
    <span id='span' class=''>Friends</span>
  </div>
  <div class='button'>
    <div id='div' class='svg timeline'></div>
    <span id='span' class=''>Timeline</span>
  </div>
  <div class='button'>
    <div id='div' class='svg messages'></div>
    <span id='span' class=''>Messages</span>
  </div>
  <div class='button'>
    <div id='div' class='svg bookmarks'></div>
    <span id='span' class=''>Bookmarks</span>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure `$('this')` is what you want to do?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 If there is a way better way to do that I will be glad to learn it :)

Comment: `$('this')` is selecting elements `<this>` which will not work at all.

Comment: this will be very easy in css. why in JS. is there any reason, check my answer has information

Comment: @Venkatraman, thank you for the tip. I did it with pure CSS :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: First I address the JavaScript/jQuery question, but note the "However" bit at the end — you don't need them at all for this.

---

Instead of `'this`' you want `.button` or `div.button`.

But that's not the main problem.

The main problem is that you're using the same `id` on more than one element. You can't do that, it's invalid, and browsers will typically use the *first* element and ignore the `id` on the other ones.

You don't need `id`s on those at all. Within your handlers, `this` will refer to the element you hooked the event on, so you can use the fact that the `div` and `span` are inside the element (via `find`) to find them:

```
$('div.button').mouseover(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.find('div').removeClass('svg-active');
  $this.find('span').removeClass('light-blue-link');
});
$('div.button').mouseout(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.find('div').removeClass('svg-active');
  $this.find('span').removeClass('light-blue-link');
});
```

Updated example:

```js
$('div.button').mouseover(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.find('div').addClass('svg-active');
  $this.find('span').addClass('light-blue-link');
});
$('div.button').mouseout(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.find('div').removeClass('svg-active');
  $this.find('span').removeClass('light-blue-link');
});
```

```css
.button-outer {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.button {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}
.button::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.light-blue-link {
  color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}
span {
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class='button-outer'>
  <div class='button'>
    <div class='svg profile'></div>
    <span class=''>Profile</span>
  </div>
  <div class='button'>
    <div class='svg friends'></div>
    <span class=''>Friends</span>
  </div>
  <div class='button'>
    <div class='svg timeline'></div>
    <span class=''>Timeline</span>
  </div>
  <div class='button'>
    <div class='svg messages'></div>
    <span class=''>Messages</span>
  </div>
  <div class='button'>
    <div class='svg bookmarks'></div>
    <span class=''>Bookmarks</span>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Scripts at the bottom unless you have a good reason to do something else -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I also changed the calls in your `mouseover` callback to `addClass` rather than `removeClass`.

---

Other things to consider:

- You could use event delegation rather than hooking the event on the buttons directly:

  ```
  $(".button-outer").on("mouseover", ".div.button", function() {
      // ...
  });
  ```
- You could toggle a class on the button itself rather than on the things inside it, and then use structural CSS to apply the styling

---

**However**, you don't need JavaScript for this at all: Just use a `div.button:hover div` rule and a `div.button:hover span` rule:

```css
.button-outer {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.button {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}
.button::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div.button:hover span {
  color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}
span {
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class='button-outer'>
  <div class='button'>
    <div class='svg profile'></div>
    <span class=''>Profile</span>
  </div>
  <div class='button'>
    <div class='svg friends'></div>
    <span class=''>Friends</span>
  </div>
  <div class='button'>
    <div class='svg timeline'></div>
    <span class=''>Timeline</span>
  </div>
  <div class='button'>
    <div class='svg messages'></div>
    <span class=''>Messages</span>
  </div>
  <div class='button'>
    <div class='svg bookmarks'></div>
    <span class=''>Bookmarks</span>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Scripts at the bottom unless you have a good reason to do something else -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for such amazing explanation of the topic. I did learned from it and the CSS approach worked perfectly. Wish you a nice day!

Comment: @Andrew: Glad that helped!

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, Argument as a string inside `$()` is a selector. It's failing due to jQuery method look out for element / tag in your DOM like below and One more below is invalid tag.

```
<this></this>
```

Try with valid selector like `$('div.button')`

Note: ID is for unique identifier. please use once. its not semantic if you use multiple times.

Efficient way will be from CSS. Main benefit will mouseout case will be taken care by browser.

```
div.button:hover {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 27px;
  width:100px;
}
```